# How can I change the result of a task given its id in celery using redis?

Tags: celery

I'm trying to change the result of a task given its id in Celery but I have not found a way to do so.

I've been trying with AsyncResult, update_state  and store_result but nothing works, does anyone know what it's the correct way?